# How to use jquery :not in Marionette ItemView events

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

How can we use `jquery :not` selector in Marionette `ItemView events`? 
eg. following is wrong, doesn't work - 
`events: {` 
    `"click #div1 :not #div2: "check"`
    `// Other events` 
`}`

Reference for `jquery :not`-  http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: reference for `:not()` selector is  http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ what you have is the reference to `.not()` method

Comment: Ok, made the change in question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
events: { 
  "click #div1:not(#div2)": "check"
}
```

Comment: @VijaySingh Great! No problem :)